# Inatalling numpy and scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I downloaded numpy and scipy but I couldn't install it. Can someone guide how to install it on windows?

I have both python 2.7 and 3.3 installed.

Thnkx!

Comment: "Couldn't install" is not a very useful description of the problem. What did you try and what happened?

Comment: At the very least you need to indicate where in the install process you are running into difficulties. What have you done so far? What are the error messages you're getting?

Comment: also the binary you downloaded ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you download the right binary

http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.12.0b1/scipy-0.12.0b1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download

http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/numpy-1.6.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download

Open python in your terminal

type `import numpy,scipy`  if there is no error you are good to go

Comment: For numpy, I got zip file. I unzipped it and I got a folder. Where should I put the folder? For scipy, I downloaded the .exe file and ran the file. But how would I know if the scipy has been properly installed?

Comment: @Mario 1. Download the numpy installer instead of sources. 2. Just try to use it. Also, if you really downloaded the sources and dont know what to do with them then you may need to learn how 3rd party python modules work.